# using monit to stop or start a service

Tags: linux, bind, monit

I would like to use monit to monitor my DNS server.
if BIND failed it should stop OSPFD.

i tried this but I get an error;

```
> check process named with pidfile /var/run/named/named.pid start
> program "/etc/init.d/named start" stop program  "/etc/init.d/named
> stop"
>         if status != 0 then stop program ospfd
```

the error is `Error: syntax error 'status'`

Comment: Could you please paste whole script so that we can understand what is problem in script? Be more specific.

Comment: # BIND DNS
check process named with pidfile /var/run/named/named.pid
start program "/etc/init.d/named start"
stop program  "/etc/init.d/named stop"
        if STATUS != 0 then stop program ospfd

# OSPF
check process named with pidfile /var/run/ospfd.pid
start program "/etc/init.d/ospfd start"
stop program  "/etc/init.d/ospfd stop"

Comment: If you could edit this into the question and indent with 4 spaces, it will display as a code block. I can't tell where the line breaks are meant to be in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming you've already looked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/701181/using-monit-to-stop-or-start-a-service).

Only watching the pid of a network service like named can be misleading. The purpose of the service is to answer network requests, so you should verify that the network port is listening and responding. If the monitor fails, you can then restart/stop ospfd via it's own init script.